# Flasque sheaves on a site

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, topos-theory, sites

This is a [cross-post from MathStackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4428946/531227).

We define a flasque sheaf on a site as one whose first Čech cohomology vanishes for every covering of every object of the site. I know this definition is non-standard, but Lei Fu's *'Étale cohomology theory'* uses it and shows it to be equivalent to the standard one (i.e, that all higher cohomology groups vanish for every object).

In the proof, he uses the following lemma which I could not prove: If $$0\rightarrow F'\rightarrow F\rightarrow F''\rightarrow 0$$ is an exact sequence and $F'$ and $F$ are flasque, so is $F''$. I am not entirely sure if this is true or if Fu has made a mistake, because I have never seen this claim made anywhere else.

Here is the relevant section from the book:

[image]

As an aside, how does this relate to the 'restriction maps are surjective' definition?

Comment: The Stacks project calls a sheaf $\mathscr F$ *totally acyclic* if $H^i(\mathbf T/U,\mathscr F) = 0$ for all $i > 0$ and all objects $U$ of the topos $\mathbf T$, and claims without details that (1) it is not enough to check on representable objects $U$ (coming from the site), and (2) this clashes with the 'restrictions are surjective' definition. See Tag [079X](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/079X). There is no remark on whether $H^1$ suffices.

Comment: I am just clarifying: are you asking whether this is true for *every* site, or just for the etale site of a scheme (the only site where Lei Fu claims that it is true)?

Comment: @JasonStarr The book makes the claim only for the étale site, but I never thought the choice of site would matter.

Comment: Exercise: on the \'etale site of a scheme, there are no "flasque" sheaves of abelian groups apart from the zero sheaf, if flasque is defined by "surjective restriction maps".

Comment: @Johan I see. For any $U$, take the covering $U\sqcup U\rightarrow U$.

Comment: Could this be a typo? The statement *If $\mathscr F'$ and $\mathscr F''$ are flasque then so is $\mathscr F$* looks much better.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth No, the book uses this particular statement in a later proof.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Note that the same statement for the other definition (restrictions are surjective) is an exercise in Hartshorne (II.1.16(c)), at least for topological spaces. But we already concluded that the notions do not agree.

Comment: @Jehu314 If you have a sheaf $F$ such that $\textrm{Ext}^1 (E, F) = 0$ for a sufficiently large class of sheaves $E$, then $F$ will have the property that "restrictions _along monomorphisms_ are surjective": given $U \subseteq V$, we can form the short exact sequence of sheaves $0 \to \mathbb{Z} U \to \mathbb{Z} V \to \mathbb{Z} U / \mathbb{Z} V \to 0$ and apply $\textrm{Ext}^*(- , F)$ to get an exact sequence $F (V) \to F (U) \to \textrm{Ext}^1 (\mathbb{Z} V / \mathbb{Z} U, F)$. The point is that in a general site, morphisms in the site are not always monomorphisms.

Comment: This is out of my comfort zone, but one should get an exact sequence $0=H^1(U,\mathscr F)\to H^1(U,\mathscr F'')\to H^2(U,\mathscr F')\to \cdots$. Without knowing $H^2(U,\mathscr F')$ this looks completely hopeless -- I would rather look for a counter example than for a proof.